# What was the Center-of-Mass Energy of Rutherfords original experiment scattering $\alpha$-particles off Gold Foil?

Tags: special-relativity, energy-conservation, scattering

I am looking through Rutherford's paper on his experiment, *The Scattering of α and β Particles by Matter and the Structure of the Atom* and am having trouble figuring out the center of mass energy in his experiment given his experimental apparatus. Specifically I am only looking for initial momentum of the incident $\alpha$ particle beam so that I can recover the maximum momentum-transfer possible such an event.

Is this information noted anywhere, or should I just try to reconstruct the incident velocity of the $\alpha$-particle from his cross-section data?

Comment: The emitter was radium, so a 4.7MeV alpha particle.

Comment: (Taken from the _On a Diffuse Reflection of the $\alpha$-Particles_)

Comment: Thank you. I'm embarrassed I missed that. I'll mention you solved it and close the question.

Comment: No problem. I have a hard time with many of the early articles because they hadn't actually figured out all the elements/isotopes yet and refer to them by now-archaic names. So much easier to turn on an accelerator and set the beam energy, but those weren't invented yet (and were a response to the desire to vary the particle energy at will).

Answer (score 1):

User Jon Custer gave me an answer. The alpha particle had an energy of 4.7MeV, radiated from Radium. Source: *On a Diffuse Reflection of the $\alpha$-Particles*